# Запись в массив

Tags: php, laravel

Есть такой функционал

```
   $arr = array();
    Excel::load(Input::file('file'), function($reader) use($arr){
        $results = $reader->all();
        foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
            $arr[$value['id']] = [
                'user' => $value['pokupatel']
            ];
        }
    print_r($arr) // работает

    })->get();

    print_r($arr) // не работает
```

Проблема заключается в том, что массив $arr недоступен за переделами функции, но внутри функции все работает как надо

Comment: проблема решена, необходимо было поставить  символ "&".

"function($reader) use(&$arr)"

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте поставить &. Так:

```
Excel::load(Input::file('file'), function($reader, &$arr)
```

Либо так

```
Excel::load(Input::file('file'), function($reader) use (&$arr)
```